# how to ignore key pressed signal in parent widget?

Tags: pyqt

my parent dialog widget get enter signal when child message dialog get enter signal.

When I close the QMessageBox with the Enter key, the login command is also signaled at the same time, and the QMessageBox pops up again.

```
enterPressed = QtCore.Signal()

def connect_ui(self):
    self.login_button.clicked.connect(lambda *args: self._login())
    self.enterPressed.connect(lambda *args: self._login())
    return

def _login(self):
    id_value = self.ID_line_edit.text()
    password_value = self.password_line_edit.text()
    user_data = self.server_data.get(id_value)
    if user_data:
        if user_data["password"] == password_value:
            self.close()
            self.parent.login_button.hide()
            self.parent.profile_button.show()
            cacher.save(self.server_data)
            return
        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self,"Login Error","Invaild password!")
            return
    else:
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self,"Login Error","Invaild ID!")
        return


def keyReleaseEvent(self,event):
    
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
        self.enterPressed.emit()
    
    super(login_dialog, self).keyReleaseEvent(event)
```

Comment: Override `keyPressEvent()`, not `keyReleaseEvent()`. The messagebox is closed when the enter key is *pressed*, so you will always receive the key release. Note that you should probably use a QShortcut for that (ensuring that you properly set its *context*).